# counter in recursiv function

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following recursiv function in python:

```
def _floodfill(matrix, x, y, counter):
    if matrix[x][y] != 9:
        matrix[x][y] = 9
        counter += 1
        # recursively invoke flood fill on all surrounding cells:
        if x > 0:
            counter += int(_floodfill(matrix, x - 1, y, counter) or 0)
        if x < len(matrix) - 1:
            counter += int(_floodfill(matrix, x + 1, y, counter) or 0)
        if y > 0:
            counter += int(_floodfill(matrix, x, y - 1, counter) or 0)
        if y < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
            counter += int(_floodfill(matrix, x, y + 1, counter) or 0)
        return counter
```

I want to count how often this function is called respectively count how many numbers are != 9 in the region.
Using he following matrix and invocing the function like: `_floodfill(matrix,1,1,0)` the function should return 2:

```
[[9,9,9],
 [9,2,9],
 [9,3,9],
 [9,9,9]]
```

what's the problem with my code?

**EDIT**
I think the function is more readable like this:

```
def _floodfill(matrix, x, y, counter):
    if matrix[x][y] != 9:
        matrix[x][y] = 9
        counter += 1
        # recursively invoke flood fill on all surrounding cells:
        if x > 0:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, x - 1, y, counter)
        if x < len(matrix) - 1:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, x + 1, y, counter)
        if y > 0:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, x, y - 1, counter)
        if y < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, x, y + 1, counter)
        return counter
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Did you test it? I doubt you can get the correct counts like that. In most cases, you `return counter`; then you use this return value in a `counter += _floodfill(...)`. So, `counter` at least doubles with each recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three remarks:

1. You don't need to pass `counter` down to your recursive calls. What would they need it for? `counter` holds the number of
   cells previously visited. Your recursive calls don't need to know how many cells you have already visited. That information moves the other way around: what you want is for your recursive calls to tell you how many cells *they* visit.
2. It's much easier to write the function and use the function if all branches in an `if/else` have a consistent `return` value. If the function sometimes returns the number of visited cells, but sometimes returns `None`, it will be super inconvenient to use; notice how you had to add `int(...) or 0` after every recursive call to fix that issue.
3. The way your matrix is stored as a list of lists, it makes more sense to me to index the rows with `y` and the columns with `x` than the other way around.

```py
def _floodfill(matrix, y, x):
    if matrix[y][x] == 9:
        return 0
    else:
        matrix[y][x] = 9
        counter = 1
        if x > 0:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, y, x - 1)
        if x < len(matrix) - 1:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, y, x + 1)
        if y > 0:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, y - 1, x)
        if y < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
            counter += _floodfill(matrix, y + 1, x)
        return counter

mat = [
 [9,9,9],
 [9,2,9],
 [9,3,9],
 [9,9,9]
]

c = _floodfill(mat, 1, 1)
print(c)
print(mat)

# 2
# [[9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list to save the counter as int are passed by value:

```
def _floodfill(matrix, x, y, counter):
    if matrix[x][y] != 9:
        matrix[x][y] = 9
        counter[0] += 1
        # recursively invoke flood fill on all surrounding cells:
        if x > 0:
            _floodfill(matrix, x - 1, y, counter)
        if x < len(matrix) - 1:
            _floodfill(matrix, x + 1, y, counter)
        if y > 0:
            _floodfill(matrix, x, y - 1, counter)
        if y < len(matrix[0]) - 1:
            _floodfill(matrix, x, y + 1, counter)
        return counter
    else:
        return 0
```

```
_floodfill([[9,9,9],
            [9,2,9],
            [9,3,9],
            [9,9,9]], 1, 1, [0])
```

Comment: Using a list with one single element to emulate a "mutable int" is a bit hacky and makes the code really hard to understand.